# Fastest way to find count of words, that starts with specified string (words are stored in AVL tree)

Tags: algorithm, avl-tree

I've implemented my own AVL tree and I'm using it as a dictionary. I'm wondering, what would be the fastest way to count all the words that starts with some string.

eg:

```
string prefix = "fa";
```

[image]

```
output: 4
```

I've got it working in O(n) however, I've heard it can be done much faster. 
I can of course hold in nodes additional information, like nodes that are below and other things like that.

Comment: How much information can you store? If you store enough, it's trivial in `O(log n)`. If you know `O(1)`, it's still possible in `O(log n)` time.

Comment: Until now, I'm finding 1st word that starts with 'fa' thats o(log n) and then I count all the (fak in example) and then I start recursive function from here, that finds those words. I can store much data.

Comment: You can achieve `O(log n)` by storing just one more integer in each node.

Comment: What would such integer contain?

Comment: The size of its subtree - and that is enough to get `O(log n)` time.

Comment: Whats the use of such counter? Let's take a look at my example picture. "fak".left_counter = 3. Still, there's only 1 word with same prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reduce the memory footprint as much as possible while keeping the same asymptotic time bounds, you can suffice with one integer per node and still achieve `O(log n)`  time (assuming constant-time key comparison).

Store with each node the size of its subtree. This can be easily updated during tree modifications.

To find the number of keys with a given range:

- Find the top element in this range. That is, the unique node that is in the range but none of its ancestors is. Call the element "top".
- If no such element exists, return 0
- Initialise sum = 1 (representing the top).
- Find the start of the range in the left subtree of "top":

  - If you descend left from a node, add the size of its entire right subtree to the sum, and add one.
  - If you descend right, add nothing.
- Find the end of the range in the right subtree of "top":

  - If you descend right from a node, add the size of its entire left subtree to the sum, and add one.
  - If you descend left, add nothing.
- return the sum.

The range for a given prefix contains all elements that have the prefix. It is important to note that the set of strings with a given prefix is consecutive w.r.t. its sorting order - that is, it's indeed a range.

The start of a prefix range is the position just before the prefix itself.

The end of a prefix range is the position just before the lexicographically first disjoint prefix after this one (`FA`=>`FB`; `FZ=>GA` when only `A-Z` are in the alphabet).

Unicode simplifies this by introducing a 'top' character that may not actually occur in a text, and compares above all other characters. That is, `end = prefix + "\uFFFF"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wiling to change data structure you could get superior performance from a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). If the trie contains static data you can get even better performance by annotating the branches with size of subtree counts (generated with dynamic programming).

e.g for [harp, hat, hi]

```
           h(3)
      a(2)     i()
  r(1)    t()
p()
```

Answer (score 1):

An AVL tree can be modified so each node will also know its "index"<sup>1</sup> (the index is the element number if the collection was a sorted array).

All you now have to do is to :

1. Search for `"FA"`, get an index `i1` of the closest yet **larger** (or equals)
   element in the tree for it
2. Search for `"FB"`, get an index `i2` of the closest yet **smaller** element in the tree for it.
3. Find the number of elements with the difference between `i1` and `i2` (distinguish between cases where "FA" is found in 1 and where it was not).

Both 1,2 are `O(logn)` - 3 is constant, thus total complexity is `O(logn)` (Actually `O(logn * |S|)`, because each compare is O(|S|) itself, and you have `O(logn)` compares).

---

(1) It is done by letting each node "remember" how much sons it has, and you can use this information to finally extract the index.

Comment: What if the collection was not sorted array? I'm getting these words from a randomizer.

Comment: The index is really hard to update during inserts and deletes.

Comment: @Patryk: I meant: Assume "FAB" is in the collection. Now assume you have another sorted array with the same content, and `array[i] == "FAB"` - then the `index("FAB") == i`. You don't actually need the array, it is only a way to explain what the "index" is.

Comment: @JanDvorak Not really, it is just one thing to add to the roll, I have done it a few years back as an excrecise, I don't recall it took me too long to add this functionality to  a standard AVL tree.

Comment: @amit then I think we're describing the same algorithm (except you're searching both bounds from the root)

Answer (score 0):

AVL-tree is not the proper data structure to achieve what you want. There is an other data structure, called radix tree, which can answer a prefix counting query in O(lg N) complexity. Each node `n` in the radix tree has from 0 to 26 children. It also has an auxiliary variable, `prefix_count`, which tells us how many words in the radix tree begin with the prefix ending at `n`. For example, here is the radix tree for the words `abbaba` and `abbacba`

```
        X <-- root node: it has no value
        |
        a <-- prefix count: 2
        |
        b <-- prefix count: 2
        |
        b <-- prefix count: 2
        |
        a <-- prefix count: 2
       / \
      b   c <-- prefix count: 1, 1
      |   |
      a   b <-- prefix count: 1, 1
          |
          a <-- prefix count: 1
```

So, to check how many word in the tree begin with the prefix for example `ab`, you just follow the nodes `a --> b`, and return the prefix count of this node. In case you don't find the given prefix, you return 0.

**Implementation trick:** each node should keep an array of 26 characters, in order to improve the complexity of all the operations.

**Implementation in psevdocode:**

```
struct node :
  let child -> array of 26 characters;
  let pc -> integer prefix counter;

struct radix-tree :
  node array[ MAXN ];
  let size -> integer size of the trie

init( rt ) :
  size := 1; // add the root

insert( rt, x ) :
  cn := 1; // root
  foreach i in x :
    if rt.array[ cn ].child[ i ] = null : // node doesn't exist
      rt.array[ cn ].child[ i ] := ++rt.size;
      cn := rt.size;
    else : // node exists
      cn := rt.array[ cn ].child[ i ];
    tr.array[ cn ].pc += 1;
```

The implementation of the `prefix_count` function will be similar to the insert procedure.

```
prefix-count( rt, x ) :
  cn := 1; // root
  foreach i in x :
    if rt.array[ cn ].child[ i ] = null :
      return 0; // 0 prefixes found
    else :
      cn := rt.array[ cn ].child[ i ];
  return rt.array[ cn ].pc;
```